# Parse markdown inside a svelte component

Tags: node.js, markdown, svelte

Please excuse me if this is a naive question.
I would like to parse markdown inside a Svelte component, something like

```
<script>
  --- import some markdownLibrary ---
  export let text; // text is a markdown param
</script>

markdownLibrary.render({text})
```

I can't use [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) or [marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) as `require` isn't available.

I feel like I'm missing the bigger picture here. What is the 'svelte' way of doing this? Any pointer would help.

Comment: To anyone new here: if you want to use markdown documents *as* Svelte components or put Svelte components into markdown, I recommend taking a look at mdsvex!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using markdown is simple in Svelte, but you have to remember that a lot of markdown libraries expect to find node/requirejs etc, so you have to configure your bundler correctly to accomodate this.

To simply use markdown in Svelte, pick a library which supports modern JavaScript out of the box:

```
<script>
  import snarkdown from 'snarkdown'

  let md = `
    # Hello

    ## How are you?

    This text is _bold_
  `
</script>

<div>
{@html snarkdown(md)}
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem with the accepted answer is that it relies on `@html` which is not secure.

There is a svelte component that renders markdown without using `@html`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-markdown

```
yarn add svelte-markdown
```

```
<script>
  import SvelteMarkdown from 'svelte-markdown'
  const source = `
  # This is a header

This is a paragraph.

* This is a list
* With two items
  1. And a sublist
  2. That is ordered
    * With another
    * Sublist inside

| And this is | A table |
|-------------|---------|
| With two    | columns |`
</script>

<SvelteMarkdown {source} />
```

Comment: Agreed that it is not secure, but we use markdown for our own copy so it doesn't need to be. I would suggest in all cases that you sanitize the input before rendering it. I'm assuming that this library does that.

Comment: This solution is beyond sanitisation. From the markdown the library builds the tree, so the labels are constrained. It would be analogous to having a query with trusted input because it's internal vs a prepared statement. Variables go on a different channel so injection is not possible

Comment: If you want to use another library like marked or snarkdown, you can always run the results through a sanitizer like dompurify before rendering.

Comment: svelte-markdown _does_ use `@html` when the Markdown content contains HTML https://github.com/pablo-abc/svelte-markdown/issues/42

Answer (score 5):

I use marked. I game the system by assigning a variable that svelte can see to marked.

```
<script>
  let _marked = marked

  let md = `
    # Hello

    ## How are you?

    This text is _bold_
  `
</script>

<div>
{@html _marked(md)}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Magidoc has a [svelte library to render markdown into components](https://magidoc.js.org/svelte-plugins/marked) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use `marked` as well.

I am fully understand that `@html` is NOT secure since it could be used in `XSS` attack but in my case, I also have full control of what should be use with `@html` so I accepted the risk and just let the ESlint warn me instead of throw an error.

```js
<script lang="ts">
  import { marked } from 'marked';

  export let markdownContent: string;
</script>

{@html marked(markdownContent)}
```

And I override the Eslint rules like this:

```
// eslintrc.js
{
    ...,
    rules: {
        'svelte/no-at-html-tags': 'warn'
    }
}
```